# Is it possible to prefill values for the tabs from prefillTabs group in docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have problem with prefilling tabs from `prefillTabs` group while creating envelope using docusign api. It's impossible to assign values through `templateRoles`, since these tabs do not have any `recipientId`. Is it possible somehow to assign values to this kind of tabs?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, here is how to do that from the C# SDK:

```
      EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, env);
        string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;

        PrefillTabs prefill = new PrefillTabs();
        prefill.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
        prefill.TextTabs.Add(new Text { PageNumber = "1", DocumentId = "1", Value = "!!!test-inbar!!!" });
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.PrefillTabs = prefill;
        envelopesApi.CreateDocumentTabs(accountId, envelopeId, "1", tabs);
```

Or you can use raw JSON API call this way:

Endpoint:

```
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[AccountId]/envelopes/[EnvelopeId]/documents/[DocumentId]/tabs
```

JSON body:

```
{"prefillTabs":{"textTabs":[{"value":"!!!test-inbar!!!","pageNumber":1,"documentId":"1","xPosition":316,"yPosition":97}]}}
```

Comment: How to do it if I'm using a template, and the prefilled field already exists in the template? 

For signer fields, it matches by the tab_label, but with prefilled fields, it replaces what I have in my template and I lose the positioning of the field. I don't have the X and Y positions of there the field should be because it its already on the template.

Comment: pre-fill tabs cannot be for a specific singer. If you want to use a template that has fields for signers, you will have to have these signers fill them or you can make another API call to pre-populate these values, but that API call must be done with a different user that has permission to act on behalf of this signer. Best approach is to modify the template and remove these fields from the signer if that signer is not expect to fill these fields.

Comment: what I did was use prefill fields, but they are weird because I can't fill them by matching tab_label as I did with signer fields. Docusign api would do nothing with the values I sent. So I had to sent the envelope as "created", read the prefill fields from api, and recreate on the envelope using the same properties (x, y), and adding the values I wanted, and after that, sending the envelope. Docusign api is a new kind of bad to me.

Comment: So your concern is that you have to make too many API calls to accomplish your scenario?

Comment: Or is your concern purely that it was complicated and hard to figure out?

Comment: The issue was the api being sparsely documented and some things are hard to figure out. Why can I send sender fields when creating envelope but not prefill fields? Why it accepts the prefill values on the create envelope request if they are ignored?  Why prefill fields doc has only a single page of documentation with incomplete snippets? Each example seems to make use of wildly different apis for different features, and if you need to mix features, you need to guess and trial and error until something works.

Comment: I feel I spent much more time figuring out things that I would if the documentation was clearer

Comment: Marcio, let me know if you still need help. It's unclear, would be easier for me to help with very simple clear questions. I do agree we can improve documentation and we will work on doing that.

Comment: @InbarGazit - I am also banging my head against the API documentation. 

I need to load rows from a Google Sheet with employee info (name, email, address) and then send them a prefilled doc from a template via DocuSign which they just sign.  

First, I create an envelope via: /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes from a template.

Then I want to add "tabs" via: /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{{2.body.envelopeId}}/documents/{{4.document_id}}/tabs but no matter what document ID I provide, I get 404...

Can you pls point me when API calls are needed to get send the prefilled doc?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question and share your code. From quick reading this - you don't actually need prefill tabs for your scenario.